# PHP Array within array issue

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the one given below:

```
{
  "quantity":"1",
  "product_id":"41",
  "option[232]":"28",
  "option[231][]":"25"
}
```

I run the above in a foreach loop as $key => $value. But when I try to concatenate them into a string, I get an **Array to String conversion** error.

Eg: `$result = $this->db->query("SELECT a.quantity quantity, b.name optionname FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."product_option_value a, " . DB_PREFIX ."option_value_description b WHERE a.option_value_id = b.option_value_id AND a.product_option_id=".$key." AND a.product_option_value_id=".$value." AND a.product_id=".$product_info['product_id']." AND a.subtract=1");`

When I remove the last entry of `"option[231][]":"25"`, it works fine. Is there anyway I can convert the `"option[231][]"` to `"option[231]"`.

I am posting to a php page via json.

Thanks

Comment: please show all of your code, e.g. the concatenate statement

Comment: Is this a JSON? Where are you looping this? Please show your entire code.

Comment: does your multi-dim array always store the desired value using the same key, e.g. is it always option[231][0]=25?  If not, how do you know where the desired value is stored in the multi-dim array?

Comment: The keys are dynamic. Eg. `option[231][]=25` or `option[232][]=36`

Comment: what's the second key, though, e.g. option[231][?]=25?  how do you store values in your option array?  To be clear, you've created a multi-dim array - the values are stored like option[231][0] = 25, option[231][1] = ?, option[231][2] = ??

Comment: There is no second key. I am modifying an ecommerce website. I think the array is passed on to another function for use later. Thats why I can't change the array structure directly.

Comment: ok - so without knowing more about the constraints on your code, the only option I see is adding another foreach loop as described in the second part of my answer.  The risk, though, is that the foreach loop will produce a string based on all values in the array - you may get 2516 if your array is option[231][0]=25, option[231][1]=16.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the print_r function to convert the multi-dim array, e.g.

```
option[231] = print_r(option[231], TRUE);
```

or, if you don't like the resulting syntax, nest a foreach loop within the existing foreach loop which executes when the variable is an array, e.g.

```
if(is_array(option[$x])){
  $y = '';
  foreach(option[$x] as $value){
    $y .= $value;
  }
  option[$x] = $y;
}
```